# How can I connect to a WCF SOAP web service that uses Windows authentication in pure xml?

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, windows-authentication

I'm trying to connect to a web service that uses wsHttpBinding and windows authentication. I can connect using WCFStorm if I configure a username, password, and domain.

I need to authenticate using on the SOAP envelope, as I do not have access to programming languages such as c#.

Basically, all I can do is make a POST request that contains a SOAP envelope. How can I construct the SOAP envelope so that windows authentication will work?

Comment: All of the examples I find are using some form of .net code.

Comment: I believe Windows authentication occurs through a "handshaking" process between the client and the service prior to the actual SOAP POST. Even if you use a non-Windows authentication process, it must be validated prior to that POST to the service. WCF supports non-Windows authentication (HTTP Basic, Forms, ...) but your client needs to support these too.

Comment: I think this is the issue. I'm not sure that I can support wsHttpBinding using the cURL command line tool. I may have to have basichttpbinding enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to authenticate using a SOAP POST it is entirely possible. But you would need to implement the ServiceAuthorizationManager class in WCF and associate it with the given ServiceHostFactory used to host the endpoint.

However I am going to assume that the WCF service is a black box for you given that you said you "do not have access to programming languages such as c# [sic]". I will assume that the .net framework side is out of your control.

I am going to assume that you have full access to the client side, but cannot use .net for the remoting call.

What you are going to want to do it is to either put Kerberos or NTLM authentication headers into your HTTP request. What is known often as windows authentication is actually one of these two protocols.
Now NTLM is an easier protocol in terms of configuration and it would be my suggested protocol if your programming environment supports it.
However Kerberos is much more widely supported.

As for how you can use NTLM/Kerberos with HTTP in the framework you ARE using. Without further information I can't help you.

You may find the following interesting:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html

Comment: Basically, all I can use is the cURL utility from the command line. Though I'm not sure if it's possible to do this with only cURL.

Comment: Quick google search shows you can. http://honglus.blogspot.hk/2010/06/use-script-to-fetch-url-protected-by.html